# SSRS Chart Axis Label Issue

Tags: reporting-services

I am developing SSRS chart and have axis label as Year and Quarter. However during report rendering i am getting "Axis Label" text in some places for quarter field. Below is the result i m getting in SSRS, which is different from expected.

Q1  Q2  Q3     Q1  Axis Label  Axis Label

2012            2013

Expected Result

Q1  Q2  Q3     Q1  Q2  Q3

2012          2013

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more information, code, the steps you are doing, etc

Comment: Can you show your report design, in particular the chart's category groups and their associated label properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on your horizontal axis and chose **Horizontal Axis Properties > Axis Options > Axis range and interval** and set the **Interval** to `1`.

If that doesnt work then set (in the same optoins) your **Axis type** to `Scalar (Numbers/Date)`.

You can also click (by the chart data) under **Category Groups > Category Group Properties > General > Label**, here you can add a custom expression for your label for each category.